# Android- onPolylineClick don't work?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps, polyline

I am adding polyline on map and I enable `setClickable(true)` but when I use from `Clickable` don't work ?

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>> {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            String color = colors[i % colors.length];
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(15);
            lineOptions.clickable(true);
            lineOptions.color(Color.parseColor(color));
            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            polyline.setClickable(true);

        }
    }
}
```

then I `implements GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener` :

```
@Override
public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
    Log.i("LOG","OK");
}
```

I can't see any `log` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this sample and resolve my problem :

```
public class PolylineDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);

    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);

    private static final LatLng ADELAIDE = new LatLng(-34.92873, 138.59995);

    private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734);

    private static final LatLng LHR = new LatLng(51.471547, -0.460052);

    private static final LatLng LAX = new LatLng(33.936524, -118.377686);

    private static final LatLng JFK = new LatLng(40.641051, -73.777485);

    private static final LatLng AKL = new LatLng(-37.006254, 174.783018);

    private static final int WIDTH_MAX = 50;

    private static final int HUE_MAX = 360;

    private static final int ALPHA_MAX = 255;

    private Polyline mMutablePolyline;

    private Polyline mClickablePolyline;

    private SeekBar mColorBar;

    private SeekBar mAlphaBar;

    private SeekBar mWidthBar;

    private CheckBox mClickabilityCheckbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.polyline_demo);

        mColorBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.hueSeekBar);
        mColorBar.setMax(HUE_MAX);
        mColorBar.setProgress(0);

        mAlphaBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.alphaSeekBar);
        mAlphaBar.setMax(ALPHA_MAX);
        mAlphaBar.setProgress(255);

        mWidthBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.widthSeekBar);
        mWidthBar.setMax(WIDTH_MAX);
        mWidthBar.setProgress(10);

        mClickabilityCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.toggleClickability);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Override the default content description on the view, for accessibility mode.
        // Ideally this string would be localised.
        map.setContentDescription("Google Map with polylines.");

        // A simple polyline with the default options from Melbourne-Adelaide-Perth.
        map.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                .add(MELBOURNE, ADELAIDE, PERTH));

        // A geodesic polyline that goes around the world.
        mClickablePolyline = map.addPolyline((new PolylineOptions())
                .add(LHR, AKL, LAX, JFK, LHR)
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.BLUE)
                .geodesic(true)
                .clickable(mClickabilityCheckbox.isChecked()));

        // Rectangle centered at Sydney.  This polyline will be mutable.
        int radius = 5;
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude - radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude - radius, SYDNEY.longitude - radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude - radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius))
                .add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius, SYDNEY.longitude + radius));
        int color = Color.HSVToColor(
                mAlphaBar.getProgress(), new float[]{mColorBar.getProgress(), 1, 1});
        mMutablePolyline = map.addPolyline(options
                .color(color)
                .width(mWidthBar.getProgress())
                .clickable(mClickabilityCheckbox.isChecked()));

        mColorBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mAlphaBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        mWidthBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        // Move the map so that it is centered on the mutable polyline.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(SYDNEY));

        // Add a listener for polyline clicks that changes the clicked polyline's color.
        map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                // Flip the values of the r, g and b components of the polyline's color.
                int strokeColor = polyline.getColor() ^ 0x00ffffff;
                polyline.setColor(strokeColor);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // Don't do anything here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // Don't do anything here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (mMutablePolyline == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (seekBar == mColorBar) {
            mMutablePolyline.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(
                    Color.alpha(mMutablePolyline.getColor()), new float[]{progress, 1, 1}));
        } else if (seekBar == mAlphaBar) {
            float[] prevHSV = new float[3];
            Color.colorToHSV(mMutablePolyline.getColor(), prevHSV);
            mMutablePolyline.setColor(Color.HSVToColor(progress, prevHSV));
        } else if (seekBar == mWidthBar) {
            mMutablePolyline.setWidth(progress);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Toggles the clickability of two polylines based on the state of the View that triggered this
     * call.
     * This callback is defined on the CheckBox in the layout for this Activity.
     */
    public void toggleClickability(View view) {
        if (mClickablePolyline != null) {
            mClickablePolyline.setClickable(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
        }
        if (mMutablePolyline != null) {
            mMutablePolyline.setClickable(((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
        }
    }
}
```